# Preventing error from causing RSpec test failure

Tags: ruby, rspec, error-handling

Suppose I have a class with methods like these:

```
class MyClass
  ...

  def self.some_class_method
    my_instance = MyClass.new
    self.other_class_method(my_instance)
    raise 'ERROR'
  end

  def self.other_class_method(instance)
    ...
  end
end
```

And the test for it looks like this:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe MyClass do
  describe '.some_class_method' do
    context 'testing some_class_method' do
      it 'calls other_class_method' do
        MyClass.should_receive(:other_class_method)

        MyClass.some_class_method
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The test errors out with `ERROR`, and if I remove the `raise 'ERROR'` line, the test passes. But here I want to only test whether `some_class_method` calls `other_class_method`, regardless of what happens afterwards. I could change it to expect the method to raise an error, but that's not the purpose of this particular test. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could rescue the exception in the test.

```
describe MyClass do
  describe '.some_class_method' do
    context 'testing some_class_method' do
      it 'calls other_class_method' do
        MyClass.should_receive(:other_class_method)
        begin
          MyClass.some_class_method
        rescue
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

What about adding an expectation that the method is raising an error. That will even enhance your testing:

```
describe MyClass do
  describe '.some_class_method' do
    context 'testing some_class_method' do
      it 'calls other_class_method' do
        expect(MyClass).to receive(:other_class_method)
        expect { MyClass.some_class_method }.to raise_error("ERROR")
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Then the test would fail if the method stopped raising an error. The test should pass regardless of whether the error is raised, and only care about `other_class_method` being called.